# Android - Blank Settings Output & Other Activities

Tags: android, settings

I had posted this earlier question: [Android Loader - Blank ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771151/android-loader-blank-listview?noredirect=1#comment47707286_29771151)

My ListView's were blank and not populated. I haven't sorted that problem yet as there were no helpful replies.

But now even the very simple **Settings activity** runs blank when selecting Settings menu. There are no errors in the project. I selected a Blank Activity with Fragment when creating the project.

**MSKSettings.java**

```
public class MSKSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference)
{

    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), "")
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value)
{
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference)
    {
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0)
        {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

**MSK.java** (Main Activity)

```
public class MSK extends ActionBarActivity
{
private final String LOG_TAG = MSK.class.getSimpleName();
private final String MSKFragment_TAG = "MFTAG";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_msk);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                   .add(R.id.container, new MSKFragment(), MSKFragment_TAG)
                                   .commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_msk, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MSKSettings.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: can I have a reply to this seemingly simple question?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to do the following:
- in the onCreate method on your settings activity, add your reference xml file with the addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.your_preference_file) method.
Note: switch "R.xml.your_preference_file" with the appropriate reference to your file
- specify default values in the preferences xml file